# merging data tables resulting in most recent year in R/Postgre

Tags: sql, r, join, merge

I have data on devices that were inspected yearly - some from 2010-2015 and some with shorter duration (2013-2015). What I need to do is merge the yearly records by device number (device_num) but only keep the most recent year.
Example:

```
device_num     year
 1D1           2012
 1D1           2013
 1D1           2014
 1D1           2015
 100f          2013
 100f          2014
```

and here I would just want the result to keep 1D1 for 2015 and 100f for 2014.
Any and all help is SUPER appreciated!
I have a main data.table with all the device numbers/years and I have created separate d.tables for each year trying to be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(year), device_num from table group by device_num
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: Thank you Red - I'm going to give that a try right now!

Comment: i used: EleMain2<-SELECT max(year), device_num FROM EleMain1 GROUP BY device_num      however it tells me there is an unexpected symbol in "EleMain2<-SELECT max". EleMain2 is the d.table I was hoping to create

Comment: What database are you using? Are you using any SQL Client?